# how to convert formula into text?

Tags: vba

I have cells(1,1)="=add(a,b)". I want modify this text and place it into some VBA variable string and NOT the result of calculation. In other words, I want to be able to see in some VBA variable the text = "=add(a,b)".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.Formula`

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim FormText as String
    FormText = ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Formula
    Debug.Print FormText
End Sub
```